# why in Codeigniter my session lost in other pages?

Tags: codeigniter, session, redirect

it's first time I use Codeigniter 3.x. after authentication for login I set session data in Login_model.php:

```
  $data_session = array(
            'PersonId' => $PersonId,
            'PersonEmail' => trim($PersonEmail),
            'PersonName' => trim($PersonName),
            'PersonFamily' => trim($PersonFamily),
            'Login' => true);
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
```

before redirect I have access to my session data by :

```
print_r($this->session->userdata()); 



 Array([__ci_last_regenerate] => 1510383844   [PersonId] => 129[PersonEmail]=> h@q.com  [PersonName] => PersonName   [PersonFamily] => PersonFamily   [Login] => 1)
```

but after redirect my session data is something like this:

```
Array( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1510384212)
```

also my setting in config.php is:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'east';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
//$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
//------------------
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'domain/admin/';
$config['cookie_path']        = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']     = FALSE;
```

I have reviewed a lot of things in this regard. but I still have not gotten a good result.

Answer (score 0):

when using

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

then `$config['sess_save_path']` must be set to the absolute path of the folder where session files are stored.

With this folder structure

```
webroot/
   application/
   sessions/
   system/
   ...etc/
```

Then

```
`$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH."sessions/";`
```

will work perfectly.

Folder write permissions must be set appropriately.

***EDIT***

You should try setting `$config['cookie_domain'] = '';` (an empty string) and if that does not work try `$config['cookie_domain'] = '.your-domain.com';`

The following controller will allow you to test if sessions are working correctly. Create a file named Test_sessions.php in your controllers folder.
Use this code.

```
<?php
/**
 * This class is useful for testing the configuration of the CodeIgniter "session" library.
 * It works only for CodeIgniter versions >= 3.0.0
 * 
 * If "session" is properly configured then each time you ask a browser for this page
 * the display will alternate between "No session data" and the value of $this->sess_message.
 */
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test_sessions extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string So you can define your own message to be displayed.
     */
    public $sess_message;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // The next line can be commented out if 'session' is autoloaded - or not, doesn't matter.
        $this->load->library('session');  
        $this->sess_message = "We got session data!";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo date("F j, Y, g:i:s a")."<br>"; //so you can tell the page actually does refresh
        if($this->session->testing)
        {
            echo $this->session->testing;
            unset($_SESSION['testing']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No session data";
            $_SESSION['testing'] = $this->sess_message;
        }
    }

}
```

Browse to `http://yoursite.com/test_sessions`. If sessions are properly configured, every time you refresh the page it will alternate between the two messages.

Comment: I changed it. but problem remains still. after login, create to session file in sessions folder. one of them have complete session data and another one just have  __ci_last_regenerate data

Comment: I created your controller and after my login I see this message:  We got session data!   there is session but there is not my data in session just there is  ci_last_regenerate.

Comment: Then most likely your session and/or cookie config is wrong. Did you change `$config['cookie_domain']` as described in my revised answer?

Comment: yeah - I changed it too

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem  by change my config to:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH.'sessions/';$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 3600;$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';$config['cookie_domain']   = '';$config['cookie_path']     = '/';$config['cookie_secure']  = FALSE;$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```